# Adding Elelments Into A PHP Loop At A Specific Position

Tags: php

I'm using a simple php script to fetch all of the articles of my blog and display them on a page with pagination.

I'm going to use the same script on my homepage, but, I want to place a special the navigation after the first echoed result, and before the remaining 5.

Here is the script I'm using:

```
<?php
$posts_sql = "SELECT * FROM publication_posts WHERE section = '".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$display_limit.""; // 6 Posts
$posts_res = mysqli_query($con, $posts_sql);
while($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts_res)){

$post_id = $post["id"];
...

$post_date = date("jS F, Y", strtotime($post_added));

$posts .= "

    <div class=\"post\" id=\"".$post_id."\">
        // Content
    <div class=\"postDivide\"></div>

";
?>
<?php
$navigation = "
// Code for navigation bar
";
?>
<html>
    <?php echo $posts; ?>
</html>
```

Is it possible to place `$navigation` inside `$posts`, after the first post is echoed out? And how is it done?

Comment: Print out `$posts[0]`. Print out your navigation. Print out `$posts[1]` to `$posts[5]`.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this but it's only showing the navigation. When you say `Print`, what do you mean. I've used `<?php echo $posts[0]; ?>`

Comment: @kerbholz : Changed echo to print, but it's still only showing the navigation. Is there somethign else I need to add?

Comment: By "print out" I meant `echo`, yes. You could `var_dump($posts);` to see what your array  ... wait. I just realized that you concat $posts, thought you made it an array. My fault, my code won't do anything then. Go with Halcyon's answer

Comment: Thanks. To be honest Halcoyn's answer looks way confusing and I probably won't be able to easilly edit or update the code in future. Your code looks simple enough, but what you you mean by `concat` preventing the code working. Can I change that in any way?

Comment: Instead of `$posts .= "` you could do `$posts[] = "` which should give you an array of posts. You can then access the elements in the array using `$posts[0]`, `$posts[1]` etc.

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly!

Comment: Ok, glad it works.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered doing something like this?

```
$posts = fetch_posts(6);

render_post($posts[0]);
render_navigation();
foreach (array_slice($posts, 1) as $post) {
    render_post($posts);
}
```

---

```
<?php

function fetch_posts($section, $start, $num) {
    global $con;
    $posts_sql = "SELECT * FROM publication_posts WHERE section = '".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$num."";
    $posts_res = mysqli_query($con, $posts_sql);
    $posts = [];
    while($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts_res)){
        $posts[] = $post;
    }
    return $posts;
}

function render_post($post) {

    $post_id = $post["id"];

    $post_date = date("jS F, Y", strtotime($post_added));

    return "
        <div class=\"post\" id=\"".$post_id."\">
            // Content
        <div class=\"postDivide\"></div>
    ";
}

function render_navigation() {
    return "
        // Code for navigation bar
    ";
}

?>
<html>
    <?php
    $section_id = "??";
    $posts = fetch_posts($section_id, 0, 6);

    echo render_post($posts[0]);
    echo render_navigation();
    foreach (array_slice($posts, 1) as $post) {
        echo render_post($posts);
    }
    ?>
</html>
```

Comment: I've added a bit more code to show how I'm fetching the 6 results form the database. I'm not technically with PHP so I was hoping for something that I could just add in easilly. I don't really understand the `render` and `slice` parts of this answer

Comment: I've written a full solution that combines your code with mine. If you implement the remainder of `render_post` it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I have to admit that this looks very confusing as someone who only does basic PHP and will need to update the code in future. I've gone with a sollution provided by Kerbholz, which easilly fit into my code. Thanks anyway though, I'm sure it will help others who may have a similar problem.